# Thread safe form close in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am just started to create a multithreaded forms application in c#

And I need to close a form from a background thread, please check below for the code.

```
new Thread(delegate () //Create new thread each time when a client request is received
{
     CH.SendMSG(P2S, $"ATGD~MatchFound~{RoomID}~{UDH.GetPlayerInfo(P1S, "Name")}~{P1S}"); //Send a response
     Thread.Sleep(5000); //Wait for five seconds
     this.Close(); //Is this call thread safe?
}).Start(); //Start the thread
```

Ok, now I want to know whether closing a UI form from a background thread is safe or not?

An if it is not safe then, Is there any alternate solution for achieving this.

Thanks a lot in advance, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: **tldr**: for UI interactions, “_always_” delegate back to the UI thread. Even if this particular operation happens to be allowed and/or “work” regardless, it’s too much needless extra to think about and sort.

Comment: I think above person is right. It looks to me like rather then making new threads you need to create task on the thread you already have. I think Task() is more what you are looking for than threads.

Comment: You might want to mention what kind of app you are talking about (Windows Forms, WPF, Xamarin,...). And, as has been mentioned, always do anything that affects the UI from the UI thread. In Windows Forms, you'd use `Control.Invoke`. And, as @mathis1337 mentions, `async` and `await` greatly reduce the need for background thread in UI-based applications

Comment: Can anyone tell me whether should I create a modal form from a background thread? Is this good idea or not? and If not What should I have to do? any alternate solution?

Comment: There is no need to do that. Why do you think you have to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that call isn't safe, you are calling form's `Close` from a thread that's not the main thread so it will crash with a cross thread exception.

To do it safely you must use the BeginInvoke function of the form:

```
//I assume that "this" is the form
new Thread(delegate () //Create new thread each time when a client request is received
{
     CH.SendMSG(P2S, $"ATGD~MatchFound~{RoomID}~{UDH.GetPlayerInfo(P1S, "Name")}~{P1S}"); //Send a response
     Thread.Sleep(5000); //Wait for five seconds
     this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Close()); 

}).Start(); //Start the thread
```

EDIT: To avoid the close to be executed if the form is closed you can do this:

```
{
     CH.SendMSG(P2S, $"ATGD~MatchFound~{RoomID}~{UDH.GetPlayerInfo(P1S, "Name")}~{P1S}"); //Send a response
     Thread.Sleep(5000); //Wait for five seconds
     this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
     { 

          if(this.IsHandleCreated)
              this.Close(); 

     }); 

}).Start();
```

Comment: OH! Thanks for your reply. But I am getting a random error when using Invoke or BeginInvoke Not happening all the time but randomly it is appearing. The error message says that "System.InvalidOperationException : Invoke or BeginInvoke should not be called on a control until the window handle has been created!", As I already told you It is not happening everytime but appearing randomly about 1 time in four or five attempts. BTW Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's because you are calling the `Invoke` after the form has been destroyed, per example if you close manually the form and the thread is executed you will get that error. You should stop that thread in the `FormClosing` event to avoid that problem.

Comment: Can you please explain me with some code to how to do this. I am very new to multithreading any help would be highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Instead of cancelling the thread I have added how to check if the handle is created, that's to avoid the thread to be cancelled while it's still executing the remote call.

Comment: Can I use Invoke in place of BeginInvoke? and if possible please explain to me in which situations does the Invoke be used? And what are the main differences between them?